# Simplifying Subformulas in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to solve an equation of the form

```
A * B * C * D * E = F
```

where `*` some complicated left associative operation.

At the moment, everything is opaque (including `*` and `A` through `F`), and can be made transparent via `autounfold with M_db`.

The problem is that if I globally unfold the definition in the formula, simplification will take forever. Instead, I want to first unfold `A * B`, apply some tactics to reduce it to a normal form `X`, and then do the same with `X * C` and so forth.

Any idea how I would accomplish this? Here's my current approach but the `in A` or `at A` doesn't work. Also, it's not clear to me whether this is the right structure, or `reduce_m` ought to return something.

```
Ltac reduce_m M :=
  match M with
  | ?A × ?B => reduce_m A;
              reduce_m B;
              simpl;
              autorewrite with C_db
  | ?A      => autounfold with M_db (* in A *);
              simpl; 
              autorewrite with C_db
  end.


Ltac simpl_m := 
  match goal with
  | [|- ?M = _ ] => reduce_m M
  end.
```

---

A minimalish example:

```
Require Import Arith.

Definition add_f (f g : nat -> nat) :=  fun x => f x + g x.

Infix "+" := add_f.

Definition f := fun x => if x =? 4 then 1 else 0.
Definition g := fun x => if x <=? 4 then 3 else 0.
Definition h := fun x => if x =? 2 then 2 else 0.

Lemma ex : f + g + h = fun x => match x with
                             | 0 => 3
                             | 1 => 3
                             | 2 => 5
                             | 3 => 3
                             | 4 => 4
                             | _ => 0 
                             end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your term in a hypothesis and `autounfold` in that.  That is, you can replace

```
autounfold with M_db (* in A *)
```

with

```
let Aterm := fresh in
set (Aterm := A);
autounfold with M_db in Aterm;
subst Aterm
```

If your `A` is too big, this will be slow, because `set` is slightly complicated and does some sort of reduction.  If this is the case, you can set up your goal so that you have:

```
HA     : A' = A
HB     : B' = B
HC     : C' = C
HD     : D' = D
HE     : E' = E
HAB    : AB = A' * B'
HABC   : ABC = AB * C'
HABCD  : ABCD = ABC * D'
HABCDE : ABCDE = ABCD * E'
------------------------
ABCDE = F
```

and then you can do something like

```
Ltac reduce H :=
  autounfold with M_db in H; simpl in H; autorewrite with C_db in H.

reduce HA; reduce HB; reduce HC; reduce HD; reduce HE;
subst A' B'; reduce HAB;
subst AB C'; reduce HABC;
subst ABC D'; reduce HABCD;
subst ABCD E'; reduce HABCDE;
subst ABCDE.
```

---

Update to account for the example:

To do the reduction on your function, you do indeed need either function extensionality, or to use a relation other than `=`.  However, you don't need function extensionality to do the modularization bits:

```
Require Import Arith.

Definition add_f (f g : nat -> nat) :=  fun x => f x + g x.

Infix "+" := add_f.

Definition f := fun x => if x =? 4 then 1 else 0.
Definition g := fun x => if x <=? 4 then 3 else 0.
Definition h := fun x => if x =? 2 then 2 else 0.

Ltac save x x' H :=
  remember x as x' eqn:H in *.

Lemma ex : f + g + h = fun x => match x with
                                | 0 => 3
                                | 1 => 3
                                | 2 => 5
                                | 3 => 3
                                | 4 => 4
                                | _ => 0 
                                end.
Proof.
  save f f' Hf; save g g' Hg; save h h' Hh;
  save (f' + g') fg Hfg; save (fg + h') fgh Hfgh.
  cbv [f g] in *.
  subst f' g'.
  cbv [add_f] in Hfg.
  (* note: if you want to simplify [(if x =? 4 then 1 else 0) +
      (if x <=? 4 then 3 else 0)], then you need function
      extensionality.  However, you don't need it simply to
      modularize the simplification. *)
```

Alternatively, if you set up your goal a bit differently, you can avoid function extensionality:

```
Require Import Arith Coq.Classes.RelationClasses Coq.Setoids.Setoid Coq.Classes.Morphisms.

Definition add_f (f g : nat -> nat) :=  fun x => f x + g x.

Infix "+" := add_f.

Definition f := fun x => if x =? 4 then 1 else 0.
Definition g := fun x => if x <=? 4 then 3 else 0.
Definition h := fun x => if x =? 2 then 2 else 0.

Ltac save x x' H :=
  remember x as x' eqn:H in *.
Definition nat_case (P : nat -> Type) (o : P 0) (s : forall n, P (S n)) (x : nat) : P x
  := match x with
     | 0 => o
     | S n' => s n'
     end.
Lemma nat_case_plus (a a' : nat) (b b' : nat -> nat) (x : nat)
  : (nat_case _ a b x + nat_case _ a' b' x)%nat = nat_case _ (a + a')%nat (fun x => b x + b' x)%nat x.
Proof. destruct x; reflexivity. Qed.
Lemma nat_case_plus_const (a : nat) (b : nat -> nat) (x : nat) (y : nat)
  : (nat_case _ a b x + y)%nat = nat_case _ (a + y)%nat (fun x => b x + y)%nat x.
Proof. destruct x; reflexivity. Qed.
Global Instance nat_case_Proper {P} : Proper (eq ==> forall_relation (fun _ => eq) ==> forall_relation (fun _ => eq)) (nat_case P).
Proof.
  unfold forall_relation; intros x x' ? f f' Hf [|a]; unfold nat_case; auto.
Qed.
Global Instance nat_case_Proper' {P} : Proper (eq ==> pointwise_relation _ eq ==> forall_relation (fun _ => eq)) (nat_case (fun _ => P)).
Proof.
  unfold forall_relation, pointwise_relation; intros x x' ? f f' Hf [|a]; unfold nat_case; auto.
Qed.
Global Instance nat_case_Proper'' {P} {x} : Proper (pointwise_relation _ eq ==> eq ==> eq) (nat_case (fun _ => P) x).
Proof.
  intros ??? a b ?; subst b; destruct a; simpl; auto.
Qed.
Global Instance nat_case_Proper''' {P} {x} : Proper (forall_relation (fun _ => eq) ==> eq ==> eq) (nat_case (fun _ => P) x).
Proof.
  intros ??? a b ?; subst b; destruct a; simpl; auto.
Qed.
Ltac reduce :=
  let solve_tac := unfold nat_case; repeat match goal with |- context[match ?x with O => _ | _ => _ end] => destruct x end; reflexivity in
  repeat match goal with
         | [ H : context[if ?x =? 4 then ?a else ?b] |- _ ]
           => replace (if x =? 4 then a else b) with (match x with 4 => a | _ => b end) in H by solve_tac
         | [ H : context[if ?x =? 2 then ?a else ?b] |- _ ]
           => replace (if x =? 2 then a else b) with (match x with 2 => a | _ => b end) in H by solve_tac
         | [ H : context[if ?x <=? 4 then ?a else ?b] |- _ ]
           => replace (if x <=? 4 then a else b) with (match x with 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 => a | _ => b end) in H by solve_tac
         | [ H : context G[match ?x as x' in nat return @?T x' with O => ?a | S n => @?s n end] |- _ ]
           => let G' := context G[@nat_case T a s x] in
              change G' in H
         | [ H : context G[fun v => match @?x v as x' in nat return @?T x' with O => ?a | S n => @?s n end] |- _ ]
           => let G' := context G[fun v => @nat_case T a s (x v)] in
              change G' in H; cbv beta in *
         | [ H : context[(nat_case _ _ _ _ + nat_case _ _ _ _)%nat] |- _ ]
           => progress repeat setoid_rewrite nat_case_plus in H; simpl in H
         | [ H : context[(nat_case _ _ _ _ + _)%nat] |- _ ]
           => progress repeat setoid_rewrite nat_case_plus_const in H; simpl in H
         end.
Lemma ex : forall x, (f + g + h) x = match x with
                                     | 0 => 3
                                     | 1 => 3
                                     | 2 => 5
                                     | 3 => 3
                                     | 4 => 4
                                     | _ => 0 
                                     end.
Proof.
  intro x; cbv [add_f].
  save (f x) f' Hf; save (g x) g' Hg; save (h x) h' Hh; save (f' + g')%nat fg Hfg; save (fg + h')%nat fgh Hfgh.
  cbv [f g] in *.
  subst f' g'; reduce.
  cbv [h] in *; reduce.
  subst fg h'; reduce.
  subst fgh.
  unfold nat_case.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks! 

Somewhat trickier follow-up: A, B, C, D, E, and F are actually functions with finite support. This means that I have to use functional extensionality and destruct to prove `AB = A' * B'` (if AB is to be a simple function, that is). Unfortunately, if I try to introduce an evar AB (say), I can't unify `1/2 =  ?AB 1  3`. 

I've tried things like the "transparent assert" from the HOTT library to construct a function that is equal to A' * B' on all inputs, but I can't extract just the function corresponding to AB from the broader proof term.

Comment: Actually, we might be able to simply first construct a function with the appropriate support whose codomain consists entirely of evars, and then do this unification process. (This might be a bit messy though - other suggestions welcome.)

Comment: I don't understand.  `A * B` is well-typed, right?  So you should be able to write down `A' * B'`.  `AB` is supposed to be a fresh variable in the context which is equal to `A' * B'` (i.e., `remember (A' * B') as AB eqn:HAB`)  Or can you do something like:
`set (AB := A * B); assert (HAB : AB = A * B) by reflexivity; clearbody AB; set (A' := A) in *; set (B' := B) in *; assert (HA : A = A') by reflexivity; assert (HB : B = B') by reflexivity; clearbody A' B'`?.

Comment: It is well-typed. The goal here is to get AB to be a simple function, though, as opposed to the product of two complicated functions. And (as far as I could tell) I needed functional extensionality to do that. Ultimately, I had Ltac construct a term `(fun x => match x with | O => ?e1 | S O => ?e2 | ... )` of appropriate size and used `replace (A*B) with [above]`, followed by functional extensionality and computation that both filled in the evars and proved equality.

Comment: Using `replace` with an evar also proved convenient, because then I could construct the desired term in the goal. It also made starting with the smallest product and building outward somewhat more natural.

Comment: Do you have a complete minimal (non)working example?  You shouldn't need functional extensionality, but I don't think I can say anything more without actual code.

Comment: Added a example above. I'm looking to replace `f + g` with `k` where `k` is a simple function.

Comment: Updated with an application to that example